# How to fix IndexError stopping the execution of code

Tags: xml, python-3.x

I need to parse all XML files in a directory and need to store their node values as variables. My code seems to fail and throw a IndexError: list index out of range and does not print more than one file.
Libraries used and imported: minidom, os

I've tried mendling with the code without any success.

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse
import os
for filename in os.listdir(path):
   if not filename.endswith('.xml'): continue
   fullname os.path.join(path, filename)
   data = parse(fullname)
   ordernum = data.getElementsByTagName('OrderNumber')
   print(ordernum[0].firstChild.nodeValue)
   quan = data.getElementsByTagName('OrderedQuantity')
   k=0
   while quan[k].firstChild.nodeValue != None:
      quantity.append(quan[k].firstChild.nodeValue)
      k+=1
   quantity.append("separator")
   print("test")
```

The append code seems to work and append quantities, but the string separator does not seem to be appended.

XML example:

```
<OrderNumber>49d569s46ads4_V45454dsa</OrderNumber>
<OrderedQuantity>6.000</OrderedQuantity>
<OrderedQuantity>9.000</OrderedQuantity>
<OrderedQuantity>4.000</OrderedQuantity>
<OrderedQuantity>3.000</OrderedQuantity>
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of how your XML file looks like?

Comment: Atleast the part of XML which you want to parse should suffice!

Comment: If I remove the while loop it executes correctly by printing both the file names.

Comment: From the [help/on-topic]: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") **must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. ** See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).* Without representative XML, it is impossible to tell you how to resolve the problem, other than to say *Fix your code so it doesn't violate the bounds of the list*.

Comment: I've added an example.

Comment: @KenWhite Can you please upvote now so that people see the question? I've fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: I tried to fix it with whatever little information you provided! Please check!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to iterate through your list, so that you don't get the `IndexError` like below

```
quantity = []
for k, q in enumerate(quan):
    if q.firstChild.nodeValue != None:
        quantity.append(quan[k].firstChild.nodeValue)
quantity.append("separator")
```

My entire code looked like.

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString

data = parseString("""<test><OrderNumber>49d569s46ads4_V45454dsa</OrderNumber>
<OrderedQuantity>6.000</OrderedQuantity>
<OrderedQuantity>9.000</OrderedQuantity>
<OrderedQuantity>4.000</OrderedQuantity>
<OrderedQuantity>3.000</OrderedQuantity>
</test>""")
ordernum = data.getElementsByTagName('OrderNumber')
print(ordernum[0].firstChild.nodeValue)
quan = data.getElementsByTagName('OrderedQuantity')
quantity = []
for k, q in enumerate(quan):
    if q.firstChild.nodeValue != None:
        quantity.append(quan[k].firstChild.nodeValue)
quantity.append("separator")
print("test")
print(quantity)
```

And the output is as follows

```
49d569s46ads4_V45454dsa
test
['6.000', '9.000', '4.000', '3.000', 'separator']
```

If you want to use a while loop, you can do

```
k=0
while k < len(quan):
    if quan[k].firstChild.nodeValue != None:
        quantity.append(quan[k].firstChild.nodeValue)
    k+=1
```

Comment: Thank you that worked! Why did my while loop not work to iterate thru the list?

Comment: That is because your while loop index goes out of bounds when iterating through `quan`, which cauess the `IndexError`. Please consider upvoting the answer too :)

Comment: Is there a way to handle it or enumerate is always the way to go?
I upvoted, but since my reputation is too low it doesn't update instantly.